# Cannot read property 'getPosition' of undefined in angular 2

Tags: angular, google-maps, typescript

When I submit button form its display error.Error is " Cannot read property 'getPosition' of undefined" . If anyone could help me out I would be very very grateful. 
Here is my code

```
 this.map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MY_LOCATION_BUTTON_CLICK).subscribe((map: GoogleMap) => {

    if (this.isViewLoaded) {

      this.map.getCameraPosition().then((camera: CameraPosition) => {

        let target: LatLng = <LatLng> camera.target;
        this.marker.setPosition(target);
      });
    }
  });


this.marker.getPosition().then(position => {

  this.place.location = position;

  this.place.save().then(place => {
    this.showContentView();
    this.translate.get('PLACE_ADDED').subscribe(str => this.showToast(str));
  }, error => {
    this.showContentView();
    this.translate.get('ERROR_PLACE_ADD').subscribe(str => this.showToast(str));
  });
});
```

Comment: where you initialise this.marker?

Comment: I think your `this.marker.getPosition()` runs before `this.marker.setPosition(target);` set value.

Comment: @hrdkisback and why you think so as error clearly stats that this.marker is undefined

Comment: @NagababuMulukuri log the marker like this.map.addMarker(markerOptions).then((marker: Marker) => { this.marker = marker; console.log(marker)}); and see what you get there

Comment: can u see my code here...https://github.com/nagababu7/NearMeApp

Comment: @ hrdkisback and @ jitender- u r right..i got same error...what do i do.

Comment: @NagababuMulukuri `let target: LatLng = <LatLng> camera.target;` have you got lat long value in `target`?

Comment: @hrdkisback- No..I tried to display some varibles on console, But directly its display the error.

Comment: same `error` you got in console?

Comment: Just trying to help you debug, are you sure `this.platform.is('cordova')` is returning `true` for you? Could you add this line to the constructor's body after the `super(injector)` call: `console.log('Platform is cordova: ', platform.is('cordova'));` and check in console for the value you get in the line saying `Platform is cordova: ` ?

Comment: @amal: I did wt u said.But it return false on console.

Comment: @hrdkisback - Yes.  It caught same error